# How to find the relative dispersion of a list of numbers over a number in it?

Tags: coefficient-of-variation, dispersion

In the game of chess a white advantage is defined as a positive number, a black advantage is a negative number, an equal position is 0.

A chess engine displays a list of the n **best** variations of a certain position on the board, starting from the best one. e.g. (from white perspective):

| Variation | Evaluation |
| --- | --- |
| Best One | 0 |
| Second Best | -50 |
| Third Best | -120 |

How would I be able to find the relative dispersion of the various variations over the best one?

I'm leaning towards using a coefficient of variation; my pain points are:

- would zero here be considered "meaningful"? From Wikipedia,

> The coefficient of variation should be computed only for data measured on scales that have a meaningful zero (ratio scale) and hence allow relative comparison of two measurements (i.e., division of one measurement by the other).

- the dispersion would be more significant as values gets closer to 0 (e.g. a list like [0,1,2] would be much more disperded than a list [998,999,1000]). How would I be able to account for it?

Sorry if these questions sound naive but I'm a noobie in the field, and thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to CV.  Could you please explain what you mean by "over the best one"?  Perhaps you could tell us, in chess terms--not statistical ones--what you are aiming to compute.

Comment: Thank you :) Sure. 

What I have in mind is a metric that, given a certain position and its related n continuations, gets how much the variations other than the best one are worse than the best one. 

This would tell me how much a certain position is _safe_ to play; i.e. how much the numbers in a list are distant from the biggest one (for white) or the lowest one (black). 

Now, what you made me think about with your comment is if comparing this list *over* the biggest or lowest number makes any sense, or if I should just compute a general dispersion measure of the list.

Comment: I can't quite grasp what you're writing about.  One problem is that any given position has nearly an infinite number of continuations (it's finite due to the three-repeated-position rule, but that could take an astronomical time to reach).  Another is that the engines don't even calculate all positions even a few plies ahead, because they will rapidly prune the very worst ones. Thus, it's not even clear what set of positions/continuations/values you are even trying to characterize.

Comment: That is a variable that you can easily set at least in Stockfish, the engine I'm using. In my case I'm looking at 5 variations per move. So my starting point is an array of 5 values ordered descendingly (in white's case) or ascendigly (in black's case). The first value is the best move.

Comment: What maybe I didn't make clear is that the 5 variations are the best ones, according to the engine

Comment: Re "didn't make clear:" I don't see that anywhere in your post!  Regardless, assuming you will make that edit, *what are you trying to ask?*  After all, you are discussing five numbers.  What property of those numbers does "dispersion over the best one" represent?

Comment: Checking again, I think I specified that the engine gives the best variations, but I'll try to make it more explicit. I would like to get a measure of how "distant" the numbers are from the first one. A simple difference wouldn't work because as I said the difference from 0 to 1 would be more important than the one between 999 and 1000 for example.

Comment: Then you need to tell us, *quantitatively,* how to weight those distances.  There's no self-evident solution.  We can't provide answers unless you can help us understand what these weights are intended to mean.  The fact that the engine gives best variations is unhelpful, because the *number* matters.  Moreover, that number varies.  For instance, when a move is forced there's only one possible variation.  The reason for offering a certain number of variations can therefore be an important consideration.

Comment: I see, and I think I would be able to do that. Do you think it could also be possible to apply the Coefficient of variation to verify the scatterness of the array in my situation? i.e. with positive and negative values and a zero value that I'm not sure would count as "meaningful"?

Comment: Might I suggest working on creating a clear *formulation* of your problem before trying to discuss possible *solutions?*  If indeed you need some kind of weighting, CoV is going in the wrong direction; moreover, it has little to do with variation with respect to the best option, which is what it seems you're after.